# angular 2 detect if any RxJS timer is running or not

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs, scheduler

I am working on angular2 application. I have scheduler requirement that runs on period of pre-configured time.

I have mainly 2 component in my application:

**1: HomeComponent,
2: MasterComponent.**

My master component will always be there in browser, all other component are it's child component of it.

Now I have added `RxJS timer` in `ngOnInit()`..

Now when I go to HomeComponent, MasterComponent is out of scope and when I came back to MasterComponnent another times starts(already first is working).. So Now I have 2 timers.

So want to detect if any times is running then not start otherwise start.

I need to start times only when user logs in.

**Master Component Code:**

```
ngOnInit() {
    let timer = Observable.timer(2000, 1000);
    timer.subscribe(this.printConsole);
}

printConsole() {
    console.log("ticks: " + new Date());
}
```

is there anyway so in **ngOnInit** I can detect any Timer already running or not !

Comment: create a static variable. but how can `ngOnInit` be fired twice if you say that `MasterComponent` is always in screen?

Comment: I have mainly 2 component, when HomeComponent load, MasterComponent goes out. That's why it loads twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a static variable on your `MasterComponent`:

```
export class MasterComponent {

  public static TIMER;

  ngOnInit() {
      if(!MasterComponent.TIMER) {
         MasterComponent.TIMER = Observable.timer(2000, 1000);    
      }
  }
}
```

Another option, and this has my personal preference, could be to create a singleton service in your application and let that service create the timer. Then inject this service into your `MasterComponent` and subscribe to the timer. For example:

```
export class MasterTimer {

   public get timer() {
       return this._timer;
   }

   private _timer;

   constructor() {}

   public initTimer(): void {
      if(!this._timer) {
         this._timer = Observable.timer(2000, 1000);
      }
   }
}
```

Your `MasterComponent` will change to this:

```
export class MasterComponent {

  private _timerSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private _masterTimer: MasterTimer){}

  ngOnInit() {
      this._masterTimer.initTimer();
      this._timerSub = this._masterTimer.timer.subscribe(this.printConsole);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
      this._timerSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Am I able to access `_TIMER` in another service or Child component ? As I want to start timer when user login and destroy when logout.. Is there any way ?

Comment: When you make it public it is possible. But if you want to create something that should be accessible across multiple components (read: more than one), best thing would be to create a service

Comment: suppose I want to start scheduler from my login service and want to have reference in my MasterComponent, is it possible ?

Comment: Yes definitely, Works exactly the same as i wrote down, but you just do `initTimer` in your `LoginService`

Comment: And I think I have to store subscription instance in my MasterComponent, right ? Also I will create `static method(to perform scheduler activity)` inside MasterComponent that will be called from anywhere.. as `MasterComponent` will always be there. And call that method inside `LoginService`.. is it okay ?

Comment: Hello facing 1 issue.. if I am initializing timer from login service. and suppose I navigate to HomeComponent then I have to add code there as well(If I directly visit HomeComponent). Then again aftet HomeComponent to MasterComponent then it call twice.

Comment: Is there any way that in whatever Component I visit it should start.. Suppose if user already logged in and after a day also he visit or open application tab then scheduler should start..
I have mainly 2 component: Home and Master(have all child component)

Comment: Just initialise the timer inside the `MasterTimer` in the constructor

Comment: thanks, hello is it possible that times will fire/run event only when user tab is active in browser ?

Comment: is it possible to pause the timer?

Comment: hello, can you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994699/angular2-rxjs-timer-not-working-properly